Does State Responsibility Arise from Supporting Non-State Actors in Acts of Genocide?
I am researching the legal implications of state support for non-state actors that commit acts of genocide. Specifically, I am interested in understanding whether a sovereign state incurs legal responsibility when it aids or supports such actions. This topic intersects areas of international law including state responsibility and the actions of non-state actors.
Articles 16 of the ILC Draft Articles on State Responsibility and Article 3 of the Genocide Convention address complicity in genocide among states or when states provide support to other states, but what about cases where a state supports non-state actors or becomes an accomplice with non-state actors in genocide?
Could anyone provide insights or refer to specific case law, judicial decisions, or academic works that address the responsibility of states under such circumstances? Any examples where international courts have dealt with similar issues would be particularly helpful.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Historically, there has been a split of interpretation. Latin American countries, informed by their histories, tend to say "yes." The U.S. and many other countries, in contrast, tend to see direct "state action" as critical and for example, do not treat mere inaction as resulting in human rights violations in most cases.
